# Redirect to login page with middleware is causing 'too many redirects" issue

Tags: python, django, redirect

What I want is redirect users to login page if they aren't authenticated. I made a middleware but the redirect is not working. Could someone give me a help?

My urls:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('contas/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'), name='login'),  # I want call this
    path('', include('apps.props.urls'))
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my middleware.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse


class AuthRequiredMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))  # Here I call login
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

and finally, my settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'middleware.AuthRequiredMiddleware',  # Registering middleware
]
```

What I am getting is this page with "too many redirects"

[image]

My log:

[image]

Comment: Just think about it for a second. 1, 2, 3. No? Ok, you send the person that is not authenticated to the login page. When he gets there, he is not authenticated, so you send him to the login page. When he gets there, he is not authententicated, so you send him to the login page. When he gets there, he is not authententicated, so you send him to the login page. When he gets there, he is not authententicated, so you send him to the login page. When he gets there, he is not authententicated, so you send him to the login page. When he gets there, he is not authententicated, so you send him to the l

Comment: Thanks! I will think in a solution to this.

Comment: Your middleware will also be applied on the *login view* itself, so it will never "reach" the login view, since even the login will keep redirecting to the login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thans to @Melvyn and @Onsem comments I have improved my code. Here is one solution (We just need to be careful with files in media folder, they are accessed as AnonymousUser):

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse


class AuthRequiredMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Here I call login if not authenticated and request is not login page
        if not request.user.is_authenticated and request.path != reverse('login'):
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))  
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```